# validate unique username from a different model

Tags: php, yii

in a form i'm working on, it will check if username was empty on registration and prompt to input a username before a user ads a comment.

i tired adding `unique` in my rules in my `comment` class, but it doesn't validate on ajax post

```
class Comment extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('username', 'unique','className'=>'User','attributeName'=>'username','message'=>"Username already exists"),

        );
    }
```

in my view

```
echo '<div class="form-group">
             '.$form->labelEx($user,'username', array('class'=>'col-md-3 control-label')).'
              <div class="col-md-9">
                '.$form->textField($user,'username',array('class'=>'form-control input-md')).'
                '.$form->error($user,'username').'
              </div>
         </div>';
 //the output looks like this
 /*<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="User_username">Username</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control input-md" name="User[username]" id="User_username" type="text" value="" />
            <div class="errorMessage" id="User_username_em_" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>*/
```

in my controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        /** @var Comment $comment */
        $comment = Yii::createComponent($this->module->commentModelClass);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
         $a=new User;
         $b=new Comment;

         $this->performAjaxValidation(array($a,$b));
         //end of Ajax validation
       .....
       .....
       .....
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ext-comment-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);

            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

the return Json is

```
{"Comment_username":["Nick Name cannot be blank."],"Comment_title":["Review Title cannot be blank."]}
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the attribute/field is required, try the `required` rules. `array('username', 'required'), array('username', 'unique')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

had to add

`array('username', 'unique'),`

in my `User` class and **NOT** in my `comment` class